# HTTPS - 407 proxy authentication required

Tags: .net, web-services, https, proxy, httpwebrequest

I'm making a call to my partner webservice by using below code. This code is working fine and able to pull the xml message from my partner in DEV environment. But, when I move this code to INTEGRATION Environment, it's giving an error **407 proxy authentication required**. When I contacted my network team, they said, my code is trying to call through proxy server.

But, As per the below code, I'm not configuring anything to call the partner service through proxy server. Could you please suggest, what I can do ?

```
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential();

creds.UserName = "partner_client";
creds.Password = "dfasnc9d3";
HttpWebRequest hwRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://res.dfadator.com/rest/requests/recent");
hwRequest.ContentType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ContentType");
hwRequest.Method = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Method"); ;

hwRequest.Credentials = creds;

// Parse the Response.
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)hwRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

The above method calling proxy server, if proxy server settings are enabled to UseProxy.
I resolved this issue by bypassing proxy server, while making call.

```
string sProxyWebAddress = null;
System.Net.WebProxy wbProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(sProxyWebAddress, true);
hwRequest.Proxy = wbProxy;
wbProxy = null;
```